# how can I install ubuntu in windows 7 32bit machine?

Tags: system-installation

how do I install ubuntu.iso (downloaded from ubuntu.com[more than 700mb]) in my windows 7 ultimate 32bit. please explain step by step.. thanks

Answer (score 0):

http://www.ubuntu.com/download/desktop

Look at the part below the download part, you have all the instructions there.